# sql запрос на поиск подходящих вариантов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не могу понять, как реализовать код, с помощью которого пользователь по заявке клиента сможет подобрать для него подходящие варианты квартир, то есть должны выводится те квартиры, где город и район будут совпадать (на этажи и все остальное прошу не обращать внимание), через join не получается :( [image: Такая вот модель получилась]

```
SELECT idflat,
       .district.districtname,
       cityname
FROM   house
       JOIN flat
         ON house.idhouse = flat.idhouse
       JOIN district
         ON house.districtname = district.districtname
```

Comment: 1. Сначала попробуйте написать сюда свое решение, отредактировав свое сообщение. 2. Согласно приложенной erd ваша задача должна решаться без проблем через join - попробуйте для начала вывести все квартиры с указанием района и города. С этим набором уже можно будет работать дальше.

Comment: @РустамАлиев, выполнил второй пункт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я даже спорить с Вами не хочу. Выкладывать кусок неотформатированного нерабочего кода - проявление неуважения к сообществу. Просто посоветую:

1. Ещё раз изучите тему с **join**`ами - вы их не понимаете от слова "совсем".
2. Раз уж вы решили писать join - указывайте его тип (**inner/left** & etc). - вам без разницы, а читабельность кода повышается (в случае с sql server - это ещё и рекомендация от производителя - Microsoft).
3. Раз уже используете **sql server** - указывайте схему (**dbo/tst** & etc.), в которой размещены таблицы, чтобы не было проблем с соседними схемами в одной БД.
4. Раз уж выкладываете код - прогоните его предварительно через какой-нибудь **sql beautifier** (есть масса онлайн решений как минимум), потому что это сразу бы показало вам ошибку в куске

> .District.DistrictName

где первая точка - причина ошибки и отвечающим на ваш вопрос было бы проше оценить правильность вашего решения.

5. Я конечно понимаю, что вы сюда не за знаниями а за быстрым решением пришли и проигнорируете моё сообщение, но чтобы вы его прочли хотя бы 1 раз и постарались к отвечающим относится с уважением - размещу ниже правильный ответ на ваш вопрос.

   ```
    SELECT k.*
      FROM dbo.[Квартира] AS k
     INNER JOIN dbo.[Дом] AS d
             ON k.[Регистрационный номер дома FK] = d.[Регистрационный номер дома PK]
     INNER JOIN dbo.[Район] AS r
             ON d.[Район FK] = r.[Наименование района PK]
     INNER JOIN dbo.[Город] AS g
             ON r.[Город FK] = g.[Наименование PK]
     WHERE g.[Наименование PK] = '<Имя города>'
       AND r.[Наименование района PK] = '<Имя района>';
   ```
6. Вы для себя внезапно открыли **алиасы** ;-)

Comment: Я не программист, а всего лишь студент, который пришел за советом, правила сообщества изучу, спасибо большое за ответ и решение